# Play 2 & Cloudbees: Could not resolve substitution to a value

Tags: cloudbees, playframework-2.1

I am deploying my Play! 2.1 application on Cloudbees.

I have in my *application.conf*:

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url=${MYSQL_URL_DB}
db.default.user=${MYSQL_USERNAME_DB}
db.default.password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD_DB}
```

I defined those values in Cloudbees configuration:

```
$ bees config:list -a myself/my-app 
Application Parameters:
  proxyBuffering=false
  MYSQL_URL_DB=jdbc:cloudbees://my-app
  MYSQL_USERNAME_DB=my-app
  MYSQL_PASSWORD_DB=yummy
Runtime Parameters:
  java_version=1.7
```

I publish my app using git (`git push cloudbees cloudbees:master`) which triggers Jenkins. But when it comes to deploying application, I get in Jenkins logs:

> [error] (compile:compile)
>   com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$UnresolvedSubstitution:
>   conf/application.conf: 16: Could not resolve substitution to a value:
>   ${MYSQL_PASSWORD_DB}

Is there anything else to do to make Jenkins aware of the configuration? Did I misunderstand something?

Thanks for your help!

Alban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration is injected at runtime, not build time. You have to find a way to make the sbt build ignore unresolved substitution.
It seems a possible workaround is to set MYSQL_URL_DB=foo, etc as build environment variables, so that the check don't break, as they won't be actually injected in your configuration

Comment: Thanks, it works!

I installed Jenkins plugin "Environment Injector Plugin" and defined the values.
That's all folks.

Answer (score 7):

You can add "?" to the beginning, so it will be treated as an override.

```
db.default.url=${?MYSQL_URL_DB}
```

You can also handle fallback situations with this approach, if you like.

```
db.default.url=mysql://fallback_url
db.default.url=${?MYSQL_URL_DB}
```

If MYSQL_URL_DB does not exist, fallback_url will be used.

Answer (score 1):

I use a config like this:

https://github.com/CloudBees-community/play2-clickstart/blob/master/conf/application.conf

and a build command like this:

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=384M -jar /opt/sbt/sbt-launch-0.11.3-2.jar -Dsbt.log.noformat=true clean compile test dist
```

And it does not worry about the missing environment variables. 
My guess is that there is a scala macro or something that triggers the compiler to resolve those variables. Adding them in is fine.

I have amended the clickstart to set default values in case they are needed.

Comment: Actually, it may be that I have that extra "jdbc" string so the URL at least is always set to something. In any case, should be ok from now on at least for new users.